# Change default gray palette dark mode color in Angular Material

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material2

is there any way to change the default gray palette in angular material?

[image: button component]

I want to change the entire dark mode gray color in the material to a custom color, for example, Slate color in Tailwindcss

[image: slate palette]

I'm trying to figure it out in the material codebase but can't find it yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we needed to override the background and foreground variables. I managed to achieve it using [this example](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6244#issuecomment-1017629612)

Currently, there is no simple built-in way to change the background and foreground color.

Answer (score -1):

To customize your own theme, you will need to follow these steps from [Angular Material official site](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

If you run into any problem, please let me know.